# Error in Firebase Authentication. (Android app)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating User signing in and I'm not able to figure out where it is going wrong. Please do help me out.
Also, Already I used the "Whether the user is signed in or not" part. It is working fine. Only signing in is not working.
Thanks in Advance.
CODE:

```
  package com.example.gayathrikasilingam.classy01;

  import android.content.Intent; 
  import android.support.annotation.NonNull; 
  import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout; 
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log; 
  import android.view.View; 
  import android.widget.Button; 
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener; 
  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task; 
  import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult; 
  import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth; 
  import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

  public class RegActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      private TextInputLayout mName;
      private TextInputLayout mEmail;
      private TextInputLayout mPwd;
      private Button mSubmit;
      String username, email,password;
      private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg);

          mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

          mName=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.pName);
          mEmail=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.pEmail);
          mPwd=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.pPassword);
          mSubmit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.regStart);

          mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {

                  username= mName.getEditText().getText().toString();
                  email= mEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
                  password= mPwd.getEditText().getText().toString();

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), username+" "+email+" "+password,
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  register_user(username,email,password);

              }
          });

      }

      private void register_user(String username, String email, String password)
      {

          mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                  .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult () {
                      @Override
                      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult  task) {
                          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                              // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                              Log.d("yaaayy", "createUserWithEmail:success");

                              Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                              startActivity(i);
                              finish();

                          } else {
                              // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                              Log.w("oops", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed.",
                                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          }

                          // ...
                      }
                  });
        } 
    }
```

Comment: have you done all previous configuration for Firebase and enabled Sign in with email and password ?

Comment: Do you have an error?